# Find if the function is surjective $f(x) = (x^2+1)/(x^2 + 2)$

Tags: calculus

I found that the following function from $f:\Bbb R \to\Bbb R$ is not one to one:

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^2+1}{x^2 + 2} $$

I found answer online that it's not surjective as the range is not equal to the codomain, where the range is $\left\{y\mid\frac12 \le y \lt 1 \right \} = \left [\frac12, 1\right)$. Can you please explain how we can get this range?

Comment: Note that $f(x)=1-\dfrac1{x^2+2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f'(x)=\frac{2x}{(x^2+2)^2}$, $f$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$ and increasing on $[0,\infty)$. Besides, $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=1$, and $f(0)=\frac12$. So, indeed, $f(\Bbb R)=\left[\frac12,1\right)$.

Comment: Thank you. You skipped the $- \ \infty $ to $0$ because it's not in the range of the function as it's always positive? Then since 1 is the maximum value and $1- 1 \ (x^2+2)$ is always going to be less than $1$, you concluded the range stops at 1 but not including it?

Comment: Since $f(0)=\frac12$ and $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$, you have $f(x)\geqslant\frac12$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$. But there is no $x$ such that $f(x)\geqslant1$, because if there was such a $x$ with $x>0$ then, since $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$, we could not have $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$; for a similar reason, we cannot have $f(x)\geqslant1$ with $x<0$. So the range is a subset of $\left[\frac12,1\right)$. And if $y\in\left[\frac12,1\right)$, then, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$, there is some $x\geqslant0$ with $f(x)>y$.

Comment: So, $f(x)>y\geqslant f(0)$ and so, by the intermediate value theorem, $x$ belongs to the range of $f$.

Comment: How you found $lim$ of $f(x)$?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+2}=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{1+1/x^2}{1+2/x^2}=\frac11=1.$$

Comment: Thank you Mr. Jose.

Answer (score 2):

Write $f(x)$ as
$$f(x)=1-\frac1{x^2+2}.$$
From this we see that the supremum of $f(x)$ is $1,$ though this is never achieved.

Further, the function is even, so we may only consider positive values. We note that $0\le x<y$ implies $\frac1{x^2+2}>\frac1{y^2+2},$ so $f(x)<f(y),$ so $f(x)$ is increasing over $\mathbb R_{\ge0}.$ It will achieve its minimum at $f(0)=\frac12.$

Answer (score 1):

Just to show that $f$ has a limited range, which is a subset of $\mathbb R$:

Taking $f(0) = \frac12$ temporarily out of consideration, by the mediant inequality if $x\ne 0$,

$$\frac{1}{2} < \frac{1+x^2}{2+x^2} < \frac {x^2}{x^2} = 1$$

Together with $f(0)$,

$$\frac 12 \le f(x) < 1$$

(this does not prove that $f(x)$ takes every value in $\left[\frac12, 1\right)$)